# Build error with gradle on a react-native project ()

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, build.gradle

I'm trying to run my react-native app on android. So I'm running the command gradlew build and I got thi error :

```
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/mlecherb/Stent/setup/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.kt: (247, 92): Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

And this is my environnement :

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.2
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 161.31 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.11.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.15.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
    Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.7 - /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-native: ^0.67 => 0.67.5
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

There is my build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = '31.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
         //googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        // classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3")
    }
}
```

And my gradle.properties :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=io-stent-mobileapp.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=io-stent-mobileapp-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=Stent2019!
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=Stent2019!

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0
```

Anything will help !

I've tried to modify the properties of sdk in build.gradle to 33 and I got this error :

```
/Users/mlecherb/Stent/setup/android/app/src/main/java/io/stent/mobileapp/MainActivity.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    return new ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(this, BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED,
                                                             ^
  symbol:   variable IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
  location: class BuildConfig
```

And same thing I don't know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

To use the gradlew clean command, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the android folder. This assumes that you have an android folder in the root directory of your project. `cd android`
2. Open a terminal or command prompt.
3. Run the following command: `./gradlew clean`. This command initiates the project clean process using the Gradle wrapper.

Once you execute the command, the cleaning process will start. It will remove temporary files, build outputs, and cached files created by Gradle.
After the cleaning process is completed, your project will return to a clean state, and you can proceed with a new build.